# Generating XPATH from an XML Document to Attribute Level

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XSLT which creates XPATH for every element in an XML file that is populated.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', name())"/>
        <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())]) != 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())]) + 1, ']')"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to extend this so that a unique row is produced 'to the attribue' level.  At the moment, one XPATH statement is produced for a given element, even if it has multiple attributes.  If an element has 3 attribues, I would want 3 XPATH lines for each generated.  Any ideas appreciated! :)Thanks

UPDATED

Hi Ian,

Really appreciate your help.

One enhancement I would need, quite tricky I think?

Where an element has an xsi:type attribute (i.e is an extension of another type), I need that to be considered in the *element name* in the XPATH and not as an attribute itself (as it is a special/reserve XSD attribute)

e.g. for

```
<a>
   <b xsi:type="c" attribute1="at1"/>
</a>
```

I need:

```
/a/b[xsi:type="c"]/@attribute1
```

rather then

```
/a/b/@type
```

which it is currently producing?  Is this possible?

Thanks!

UPDATE

That worked perfectly thanks! One last request pretty please. :) Can you tweak it to add the element or attributes VALUE from the XML, seperated from the XPATH part by a comma delim.....so is [XPATH],[VALUE]

Comment: Hi Ian,

Really appreciate your help.

One enhancement I would need, quite tricky I think?

Where an element has an xsi:type attribute (i.e is an extension of another type), I need that to be considered in the *element name* in the XPATH and not as an attribute itself (as it is a special/reserve XSD attribute)

e.g. for

    <a>
       <b xsi:type="c" attribute1="at1"/>
    </a>

I need:

    /a/b[xsi:type="c"]/@attribute1

rather then

    /a/b/@type

which it is currently producing?  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd pull out the path generating code into another template and then call into that from templates for elements and attributes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

  <xsl:template mode="path" match="*">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', name())" />
      <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())]) != 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',
          count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())]) + 1, ']')" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="not(*)">
      <!-- this element has no children, print its path -->
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="path" select="." />
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <!-- for an attribute, print the path to its containing element ... -->
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="path" select=".." />
    <!-- ... followed by "/@attributename" -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('/@', name(), '&#xa;')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's a convenient oddity of the XPath data model that while attribute nodes are not considered to be children of their host element node, the element *is* considered to be the parent of its attribute nodes.

---

Update: to handle the `xsi:type` requirement, you should just be able to add that logic to your current sibling-counting code, to treat typed elements differently. And to add the values you need a suitable `value-of` in the appropriate places.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

  <xsl:template mode="path" match="*">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', name())" />
      <!-- for typed elements, include the type in the path -->
      <xsl:if test="@xsi:type">
        <xsl:text>[@xsi:type = '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@xsi:type" />
        <xsl:text>']</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current()) and 
            @xsi:type = current()/@xsi:type]) != 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',
          count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current()) and 
            @xsi:type = current()/@xsi:type]) + 1, ']')" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="not(*)">
      <!-- this element has no children, print its path -->
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="path" select="." />
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <!-- for an attribute, print the path to its containing element ... -->
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="path" select=".." />
    <!-- ... followed by "/@attributename" -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('/@', name(), ',', ., '&#xa;')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Since the string value of an empty node set is the empty string, doing `@xsi:type = current()/@xsi:type` on elements that don't have an `xsi:type` *is* safe and will produce the correct result.

You might also want to add

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:type" />
```

if you don't want to generate paths to the type attributes.

It's worth noting here that the type logic and the counting are orthogonal - given

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <a xsi:type="xs:string">aaa</a>
  <a xsi:type="xs:integer">1</a>
  <a xsi:type="xs:string">bbb</a>
  <a xsi:type="xs:integer">2</a>
</root>
```

you would get paths of

```
/root/a[@xsi:type = 'xs:string'],aaa
/root/a[@xsi:type = 'xs:integer'],1
/root/a[@xsi:type = 'xs:string'][2],bbb
/root/a[@xsi:type = 'xs:integer'][2],2
```

with the counts per type (which is correct, the XPaths would select the right thing assuming the correct namespace bindings).

Comment: Ive updated the question, not sure if you can help with a 'minor' tweak Ian? Ta

Comment: @user2992225 how about this?  BTW, in future it may be worth considering making major changes like this into a new question rather than editing an existing one that already has a correct answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks!  One last request pretty please. :)  Can you tweak it to add the element or attributes VALUE from the XML, seperated from the XPATH part by a comma delim.....so is [XPATH],[VALUE]

Comment: @user2992225 that's a fairly simple addition, but beat in mind it'll mess up your format if any of the element or attribute values contain newlines (literal or as `&#` escapes).